# Adding user that is outside my organisation permission to push to a single branch on GitHub?

Tags: git, github, permissions, gitlab, git-branch

Is there any way I can add a user, that is outside my organisation, permission to push to a single branch on GitHub? Ideally all done through GitHub's API.

Or is this possible on GitLab?

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You can add the person from outside of your organization as an ‘Outside Collaborator’.
An outside collaborator is a person who isn’t explicitly a member of your organization, 
but who has Read, Write, or Admin permissions to one or more repositories in your organization.

Here are the steps from GitHub’s help page ‘[Adding outside collaborators to repositories in your organization](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-outside-collaborators-to-repositories-in-your-organization/)’:

> 1. In the top right corner of GitHub, click your profile photo, then click **Your profile**.
> 2. On the left side of your profile page, under "Organizations", click the icon for your organization.
> 3. In the organization's **Repositories** tab, click the name of a repository, or search for the repository by name.
> 4. Under your repository name, click **Settings**.
> 5. In the left sidebar, click **Collaborators & teams**.
> 6. Under "Collaborators", type the name of the person you'd like to give access to the repository, then click **Add collaborator**.
> 7. Next to the new collaborator's name, choose the appropriate permission level: *Write*, *Read*, or *Admin*.

An important thing to note is that you can also enable two factor authentication for outside collaborators
(and even for internal members): [Requiring two-factor authentication in your organization](https://help.github.com/articles/requiring-two-factor-authentication-in-your-organization/)

Comment: After adding a collaborator, you can [enable branch restrictions](https://help.github.com/articles/enabling-branch-restrictions/) on all your branches and allow only your normal team members to edit the restricted branches.